Why does the guardian who admits guilt pay more than when his guilt is established by witnesses?
The Mishnah Bovo Kamo 9 (7) speaks about a guardian who denies receiving the object he was to look after.  If the guardian swore falsely and then wished to atone for his transgression, he must return the object, plus an added fifth and bring a sacrifice. If witnesses testify against him that he consumed it, he need pay [only] the value. But if he confessed it of himself, he must repay the value and the [added] fifth and bring a Guilt-offering.

If the owner asked the bailee: Where is my deposit? And the bailee
said to him: It was lost. And the owner said: I administer an oath to
you, and the bailee said: Amen, therefore accepting the oath; and the
witnesses testify about the bailee that he consumed it, then he must
pay the principal. If the bailee admitted on his own that he had taken
a false oath, then he must pay the principal and the additional
one-fifth payment, and bring a guilt-offering.

So where the bailee admitted his sin, he has to pay the fifth and bring the offering, whereas where he did not admit and witnesses established his guilt, he does not pay the fifth nor  bring the offering.
At first sight this seems unjust – I might have thought the bailee would have to expend more when his sin was established by witnesses.
This payment and the guilt-offering are clearly the command of the Torah and that is the answer - it is the decree of the Torah as it says

when one has thus sinned and, realizing guilt, would restore either
that which was gotten through robbery or fraud, or the entrusted
deposit, or the lost thing that was found,  or anything else about
which one swore falsely, that person shall repay the principal amount
and add a fifth part to it. One shall pay it to its owner upon
realizing guilt.  Then that person shall bring to the priest, as a
penalty to Hashem, a ram without blemish from the flock, or the
equivalent, as a guilt offering.

But I wonder whether those commentators who offer reasons for the mitzvos have anything to say on the subject.
I could offer a partial answer that the offering will effect atonement when he admits of his own accord but a korban is not powerful enough where witnesses establish his guilt.

The reason why the guardian whose claim was disproven by witnesses doesn't bring a sacrifice is because the sacrifice requires the the person to confess his sins (Bamidbar 5:7), and someone who denies he ever committed the crime can't confess to it (Bartenura) or receive atonement for it (Rambam Gezela 7:8).
Therefore, if the thief confesses after the witnesses testified, he would bring the sacrifice and pay the fifth (Tosafot 108a ד"ה ובאו; also implied by the above Rambam). The obligation to pay the fifth and bring the sacrifice would then have nothing to do with whether the guilt was established by witnesses or not: it depends only on whether the person admitted to the crime, whether before or after the witnesses came.
However, there is apparently1 another opinion that the thief only pays the fifth if witnesses didn't testify against him (Rashi Shevu'ot 49a ד"ה ה"ג היכן שורי, as understood by Mar'e Hapanim Shevu'ot 8:3 ד"ה בין; I owe the reference to ArtScroll's Ryzman edition of the Mishnah, which also quotes Yad David on Shevu'ot 49a, which I don't have access to). According to this view, your question would stand: why doesn't a thief who was exposed by witnesses also need atonement? I didn't find this addressed.
1 I wonder if this is actually Rashi's view, since his words could be interpreted differently (הודה מעצמו שלא באו עדים, i.e. confessing by yourself means not by the testimony of witnesses, regardless of whether they were previously involved, although this explanation is more difficult in the Bartenura whose words are עד שלא באו עדים).
